# Evaluation of integrals of the cross products of vector spherical harmonics

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics

**Context**

I am studying spherical multipole radiation. I am seeking identities pertaining to the same.

Given the properties and orthogonality relation of the vector spherical harmonics [1], what do the following integrals evaluate to?

\begin{align}
\int\mathbf{Y}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{Y}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega .
\\
\int\mathbf{\Psi}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{\Psi}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega. 
\\
\int\mathbf{\Phi}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{\Phi}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega .
\\
\int\mathbf{Y}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{\Psi}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega   .
\\
\int\mathbf{Y}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{\Phi}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega  . 
\\
\int\mathbf{\Psi}_{\ell m}\times  \mathbf{\Phi}^*_{\ell'm'}\,d\Omega  .
\end{align}

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics

Comment: @Andrei Where in that link are the integrals of cross products?

Comment: The integrals of cross products is not found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics